# Ultrafilter lemma for arbitrary lattice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, lattice-theory, ultrafilters

Can someone kindly confirm whether the ultrafilter lemma for arbitrary (i.e., not necessarily Boolean) bounded lattices is equivalent to Zorn's lemma?

To be precise, if $\mathbf{L} = (L, \leq, \land, \lor, 0, 1)$ is a bounded lattice, then an *$\mathbf{L}$-filter* is a non-empty subset $F \subseteq L$ such that
(i) for any $x, y \in F$, there exists some $a \in F$ such that $a \leq x \land y$, and
(ii) if $x \in F$, $z \in L$, and $x \leq z$, then $z \in F$.

A generalized version of the ultrafilter lemma would be that every proper $\mathbf{L}$-filter can be extended to an $\mathbf{L}$-ultrafilter. When $\mathbf{L}$ is a Boolean algebra (such as the power set of a non-empty set equipped with the standard set-theoretic operations), we have the well-known result that the ultrafilter lemma is equivalent to the Boolean prime ideal theorem, the compactness theorem for PL, etc., and that these are strictly weaker than the axiom of choice. But when $\mathbf{L}$ is an arbitrary lattice, I suppose that Krull's theorem and hence Zorn's lemma can be derived from the ultrafilter lemma. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: You have defined $L$-filter, but not $L$-ultrafilter. Is an $L$-ultrafilter just a maximal $L$-filter?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes, an $L$-ultrafilter would in this case just be a proper $L$-filter that is not properly contained in a proper $L$-filter.

Comment: Maybe the tag ([tag:axiom-of-choice]) would be suitable here? (If I understand the question correctly, it is a question whether a certain statement is equivalent to AC.)

Comment: Note that you need to restrict to *bounded* lattices. Your notation $(L, \leq, \wedge, \vee)$ suggests that you are not making this assumption. Otherwise, it's not true that each filter extends to a maximal filter. For example, the real line with the standard order is a lattice which has no maximal filter at all.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing out this counterexample. In the standard context where a filter is defined as a subset of some power set, the proof that AC => UL using Zorn's lemma tends to invoke the result that a filter $F$ is proper if and only if $\emptyset \notin F$. When I was considering the more general case of an arbitrary lattice, I noticed that the analogue of this argument doesn't apply if the lattice does not have a smallest element.

Comment: Bounded is not quite enough, since one also needs to require $0\neq 1$ (as Martin mentions in a comment below), since the one-point lattice also has no proper filters.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Forgive me if I have misunderstood your comment, but since the ultrafilter lemma is vacuously true for a one-point lattice, why do we require the additional assumption that $0 \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Depends on if you take the statement to be: every proper filter extends to an ultrafilter, or: every such-and-such lattice admits an ultrafilter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is equivalent to AC.

Consider any collection $A$ of nonempty sets, and let $\newcommand\P{\mathbb{P}}\P$ be the set of partial choice functions, so that $p\in\P$ if and only if $p$ is a partial function on $A$ for which $p(a)\in a$ for every $a\in\text{dom}(p)$. We place the forcing order on $\P$, so that $q\leq p$ if $q$ extends $p$ to a larger domain, or equivalently, $p=q\upharpoonright\text{dom}(p)$. In particular, being lower in the order means having more information, larger domain, and so on. The empty function is at the top, the largest element of $\P$. Let us also add an object $\bot$ to $\P$ below all others.

The motivating idea is that $\P$ is the forcing notion that adds a choice function for $A$, augmented with $\bot$.

This is a nontrivial bounded lattice, because any two partial functions $p$, $q$ have a least upper bound $p\vee q$, which is their common part as functions, and a greatest lower bound, which is their union $p\cup q$ if they are compatible as functions, and otherwise $\bot$.

I assume that ultrafilters for you cannot be the whole lattice (since otherwise the ultrafilter assertion would become trivialized). Every proper filter in $\P$, I claim, gives rise to a unifying limit partial choice function, the union of the all the functions in the filter, since the filter cannot contain $\bot$ and so all elements of it must be compatible as functions. Furthermore, the limit function arising in this way from an ultrafilter must be totally defined on $A$, since otherwise we could extend it by defining the choice function on one more set $a\in A$ in the collection.

So from an ultrafilter in $\P$ we get a choice function on $A$.

Let me add a note about distributivity, since the lattice $\P$ is not generally a distributive lattice, one for which $p\vee(q\wedge r)=(p\vee q)\wedge (p\vee r)$. The reason is that it could be that $q$ and $r$ are incompatible, which would make $q\wedge r=\bot$ and consequently the LHS would be $p$, but if $q$ and $r$ differ from $p$ on some point $a\in\text{dom}(p)$, then the RHS will be strictly above $p$, lacking that point $a$ in its domain.

So a question remains, I suppose, about the strength of the ultrafilter lemma for distributive lattices. [**Update** Keith Kearnes posted an answer with references to Herrlich & Klimosky, showing that it is also equivalent to AC with nontrivial bounded distributive lattices.]

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'd expect the ultrafilter lemma  for distributive lattices to follow from the boolean prime ideal theorem. The idea is that we can get an ultrafilter on $L$ by using a suitable ultrafilter on the set of finite subsets of $L$ to "average" ultrafilters on the finitely generated sublattices of $L$. This should work because finitely generated distributive lattices are finite (unlike finitely generated lattices in general). Unfortunately I don't have time now to check details.

Comment: I think that Goldstern's alphabet convention should become standard when discussing forcing.

Comment: What is the alphabet convention? Is it something about which letters we should use to denote conditions?

Comment: The ultrafilter lemma for distributive lattices is equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma for Boolean algebras, as every nontrivial distributive lattice admits a homomorphism into a nontrivial Boolean algebra (so a homomorphism to the 2-element lattice from the latter yields one from the former. If we also want the ultrafilter to extend a given proper filter, start by quotienting the distributive lattice suitably). Indeed, it is relatively straightforward to see syntactically that the homomorphism from a lattice to the free Boolean algebra upon it is injective iff the lattice is distributive.

Comment: The alphabet convention is essentially a weak order reversing homomorphism into the alphabet. Namely, $p$ will never be a stronger condition than $q$, and more generally stronger conditions appear later in the alphabet (or with larger indices, etc). It is like hinting to a compiler, and once you get used to it, it makes reading very smooth.

Comment: Perhaps I ought provide more detail on why a distributive lattice embeds into its free Boolean algebra. It suffices to show that given a distributive lattice L and an element x in L, there is some injective homomorphism from L to another distributive lattice such that the image of x is complemented. And to obtain such an embedding complementing x, consider the map from L to (elements of L ≤ x, elements of L ≥ x) given by conjunction and disjunction with x. This is indeed an injective homomorphism to a distributive lattice, and the image of x is (x, x) with complement (False, True)

Comment: By the way, as the remaining questions go, Herrlich had a whole section in his Axiom of Choice book about ultrafilters on lattices.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think I shall adopt that convention, although I fear it will mean I'll be talking often about q and r, whereas formerly I would have p as the main condition under discussion, and I'm not sure I like that.

Comment: @SridharRamesh Your comment seems to be contrary to Keith's answer. What is the resolution?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited to follow the alphabetic forcing convention.

Comment: @SridharRamesh The preimage of a maximal filter might not be maximal, since without surjectivity the filter in the target Boolean algebra might avoid the image of the homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, the resolution is that I was thinking of an ultrafilter as a lattice homomorphism to the 2 element lattice, rather than as a maximal proper filter. These are essentially equivalent concepts for a Boolean algebra, but not for a general distributive lattice.

Comment: And of course, for a non-distributive lattice such as M3, we may have no lattice homomorphism to the 2 element lattice. I should've paid more attention to the definition of "ultrafilter" being used in this question.

Comment: The ultrafilter lemma for arbitrary (bounded!) lattices is easily derived from the ultrafilter lemma for (bounded!) distributive lattices: each lattice $L$ embeds as a bounded meet-semilattice into the distributive lattice $D$ of non-empty finitely generated downsets of $L$ (map $a$ to the principal downset generated by $a$). If $G$ is a maximal filter of $D$, then its restriction to $L$ is a maximal filter $F$ of $L$: given non-zero $x \in L-F$, there is $g \in G$ with $g \wedge x = \bot$ in $D$, but $G$ is prime and $g$ is a join of elements of $L$, so $f \wedge x = \bot$ for some $f \in F$.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the question about the strength of the ultrafilter lemma for distributive lattices, let me cite the relevant theorem from Herrlich's book:

**Theorem 4.32.** Equivalent are:

1. Every lattice has a maximal filter.
2. Every complete lattice has a maximal filter.
3. Every distributive lattice has a maximal filter.
4. Every closed lattice has a maximal filter.
5. AC.

In this theorem a *closed lattice* is a lattice that is isomorphic to the lattice of closed subsets of a nonempty topological space (Definition 4.28).

Herrlich, Horst
[Axiom of choice](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/11601562) 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1876.
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2006.

Herrlich credits the equivalence of Item 3 and Item 5 to

G. Klimowsky. 
[El Theorema de Zorn y la existencia de filtros e ideales
maximales en los reticulados distributivos.](https://inmabb.criba.edu.ar/revuma/pdf/v18n4/p160-164.pdf)

Rev. Union Mat. Argentina, 18:160-164, 1958.

Where Herrlich writes in terms of AC and in terms of the existence of a maximal filter, Klimowsky writes that Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to *'En todo reticulado distributivo con primer elemento, todo filtro está contenido en un ultrafiltro'. (In every distributive lattice with first element, every filter is contained in an ultrafilter.)*

Comment: Thanks. I was too lazy to open the book and write an answer, and when Joel posted his answer to the question at hand, I figured it wasn't as relevant. But I'm glad that someone took the time.

Comment: In light of Adam's comment, shouldn't the theorem be about bounded lattices?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins On [page 57](https://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA57) in the edition I have here: 
"For convenience we adopt the following slightly restricted definition of lattices. (By standard terminology our lattices would have to be called non–trivial bounded lattices.)
Definition 4.27. A lattice is a partially ordered set $L$ in which each finite subset $F$ has an infimum, $\inf F$, and a supremum, $\sup F$, (in particular L has a smallest element, $0=\sup\emptyset$, and a largest element, $1=\inf\emptyset$) and such that $0\ne1$." (I suppose it should be mentioned.)